# Joomla 3.9 CORS error

Tags: development, url, security

I'm trying to allow CORS on my website but I can't get it to work.
I've seen many posts about this, from updating .htacces, httpd.conf, meta tags, and php headers, but nothing worked. I always get a CORS error when my script tries to download a file from the CDN.

**Here is the script:**

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // this doesn't change anything
?>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"   // as above
      content="default-src 'self'  mediafire.com   *.mediafire.com;">

<video
    id="fplayer"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9"
    controls
    preload="none"
    <source src="https://www.mediafire.com/file/myfile.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"> 
</video>
```

**.htaccess**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

**Apache conf**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

**The error message in the browser**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.mediafire.com/file/myfile.m3u8' from origin 'https://www.fempton.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.mediafire.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Links I've seen:

- https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-apache-web-server/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP
- https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

I restarted Apache and the VPS too. No changes, still get the CORS error.

Comment: Perhaps mediafire don't allow access to files externally?

Comment: They allows 'direct access' to files.  I raised a ticket ..